# Integrating Twitter into iOS 4.3+ App

Tags: iphone, ios, twitter, sharing

I'm trying to integrate Twitter with my App right now. I have successfully set up the iOS 5 TWTweetComposeViewController, but this does not work on iOS 4.3. What's the best method to also integrate Twitter posting into iOS 4.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Sharekit](http://getsharekit.com/) is a framework that may help you to setup Twitter on iOS version pre 5. If you take a first look at Sharekit, it may look like you only can use it as a complete framework. But read on: you can use any of the fractions (Twitter, Facebook etc) of Sharekit to connect with your own GUI.

Comment: This is absolutely genius and I can't believe it's free to use for commercial purposes. Thanks!

Comment: Dont use ShareKit, ultimately you'll waste more time than you thought

Comment: What Saqib said. It seems cool at first, but if you want to do anything beyond the basic stuff you'll regret using it.

Answer (score 3):

[DETweetComposeViewController](https://github.com/doubleencore/DETweetComposeViewController)

Open source. Mimics TWTweetComposeViewController. Works with iOS 4 and later.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom library and implement the tweet screens yourself. Alternatively you could redirect the user to a `twitter://` URL which will open the Twitter application, or just open a Web Intent. http://dev.twitter.com